# Cant connect to a winscp ftp server with ftplib

Tags: python, ftp, winscp, ftplib

Hi im trying to code a discord bot that can upload files to a winscp ftp but i cant even establish a connection to the server. Here is the code im using (password, username and ip are not the actual im using).

```
from ftplib import FTP

# Connect and login at once
with FTP(host='123.456.78.900', user='user', passwd='password') as ftp:
    print(ftp.getwelcome())
```

when i run the codei get this error TimeoutError: [WinError 10060]

any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: There's nothing like *"winscp ftp server"*. What do you mean by it? + Can you connect to that FTP server from the *same machine* that runs the bot using any commandline/GUI FTP client? Show us its log file.

Comment: Sounds like a network issue. Try connecting from the same machine with plain old ftp on the shell. Check for a firewall or permissions.

Comment: Pardon i meant its a remote dekstop

Comment: So is it remote desktop (RDP) or FTP?